# How to get element with specific data attribute which created by JQuery.data()?

Tags: jquery, selector, custom-data-attribute

I know JQuery already has method to select elements with data attribute, which looks like

```
$("[data-attr='value']")
```

However, if you put data into a HTML element with JQuery.data() method like

```
$("button").data("attrName", "attrValue");
```

instead of

```
$("button").attr("attrName", "attrValue");
```

You won't really get

```
<button data-attrName="attrValue"> </button>
```

Hence, you can't use

```
$("button[data-attrName='attrValue']")
```

to get this button.

So, as title.
Is there any way to select an element with specific data attribute which created by JQuery.data() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `data` attribute was added through jQuery's `data()` method then it will not be available in the DOM, hence attribute selectors won't work - as you've discovered.

The alternative is to use `filter()`, like this:

```
var $button = $('button').filter(function() {
  return $(this).data('attrName') == 'attrValue';
});
```